# Did someone do any research on System Designer vs. JSON Schema?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I am looking for a technology in JavaScript to model my system , to create instances and to be capable to verify created instances against Meta-model, similar to UML.

I found that there are two separate approaches:

1. System Designer : https://designfirst.io/systemdesigner/
2. JSON Schema: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html

It looks like both approaches can be used for this purpose. However, I am interested, whether someone already did a deeper approach and compared the technologies.

What I expect is a summary of features, for example:

- System Designer supports inheritance, JSON Schema not.
- Automatic initialization is not supported in JSON Schema.

Comment: Hi there. You're question is about to get closes because asking for opinions or off site resources are off topic. As an aside, these two things are not comparable. They are made for and do different things. JSON Schema is primarily for validation, and is not designed to map to code classes.

Comment: Frankly speaking, the question is about solution to model a system, to create instances and to verify instances in javascript. The opinion about found technologies would be great on top. Since you are mentioning they are for different purposes, it would be great to know if you can combine them.

Comment: You've asked for people to share their experience or opinions on something. That's considered off topic as it can generate discussion. You may find it useful to read the SO tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour - If you rephrase your question to ask for factual information, then you'll avoid this issue in relation to SO rules. Please try not to see this as personal, as you're new here. The community can be really great, but can initially seem unfriendly because of the rules.

Comment: If System Designer does all you need, then there's no reason to use JSON Schema. Disclaimer: I'm part of the JSON Schema core team.